# Is it possible to put this method in the parent class instead?

Tags: java, return, arguments, polymorphism, parent-child

I have a method sleep() which sets int hp of the instance to final int MAX_HP. I have placed this method inside the Warrior and Mage classes, which are the child classes of Character. The problem here is that I define MAX_HP individually within each child class as Warrior's and Mage's would have different Max_HP's, so it seems like I have to also declare sleep() within each class instead of just once in the parent class - inefficient. Is there a way I can declare the sleep method in the parent class and somehow retrieve the MAX_HP's from within the child classes? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
//Warrior Class
public class Warrior extends Adventurer{
    private final int MAX_HP = 150;
    public void sleep(){
    setHp(MAX_HP);
    System.out.println(getName() + "fully restored HP!");
 }
}

//Mage Class
public class Mage extends Adventurer{
    private final int MAX_HP = 100;
    public void sleep(){
    setHp(MAX_HP);
    System.out.println(getName() + "fully restored HP!");
 }
}

//Adventurer Class
public abstract class Adventurer{
private int hp;
public Adventurer(int hp){
    this.hp = hp;
 }
public int getHp(){
    return this.hp;
 }
public void setHp(int hp){
    this.hp = hp;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

Inside the abstract class `Adventurer` add an abstract method:

```
public abstract int getChildHP();
```

and have `Warrior` and `Mage` implement it:

```
public int getChildHP() { return MAX_HP };
```

(`MAX_HP` is different for each one of them of course).

Move the `sleep()` method (delete it from the children) to the abstract class and implement it:

```
public void sleep() {
    setHp(getChildHP());
    System.out.println(getName() + "fully restored HP!");
}
```

When this method is called, the relevant getChildHP() will be called according to the instance.
Now `sleep()` exists only once in the parent class ==> no code duplication.

Hope it helps.